# writing a string into another using procedure call in mips

Tags: mips

hey guys I've got a practice that I couldn't do and it's basically asking to write a string into another using procedure call this is my code:

```
.data

S: .ascii "My Name is Suliman."
T: .asciiz ""

.text

main:

la $s0, S            # Load address of first character
la $s1, T            # Load the address of second string

jal loop
sw $v0, T

j done

function:

 li $v0, 0   # this is T

loop:

lbu  $t2, 0($s0)        # Load the first byte of $s0 (str1) into $t2

sb   $t2, 0($v0)        # Save the value in $t2 at the same byte in $s1 (T)

addi $s0, $s0, 1        # Increment both memory locations by 1 byte
addi $v0, $v0, 1

bne  $t2, $zero, loop   # Check if at the zero delimiter character, if so jump to 
jr $ra
done:

li $v0, 4
la $a0, T
syscall                 # Print the copied string to the console

li $v0, 10              # Program end syscall
syscall
```

but I keep getting this error does anyone have an idea about it?
Error in /Applications/Q3.asm line 23: Runtime exception at 0x00400028: address out of range 0x00000000

Go: execution terminated with errors.

Comment: `sb   $t2, 0($v0)     # Save the value in $t2 at the same byte in $s1 (T)`  <-- What you're actually doing there does not match what you say you're doing in the comment (pay close attention to which registers you're using).

Comment: can you please try to specify where i didn't because I really hate this course and I need to finish it

Answer (score 1):

.data

```
S: .asciiz "My Name is Ahmed Edhi"
T: .asciiz ""
```

.text

main:

```
la $s0, S            
la $s1, T            

move $a0, $s0   # $a0, $a1 used as argument of procedure loop
move $a1, $s1
jal loop
j print
```

loop:

```
  # void method
  # no return statement here, if required use $v0, $v1 to return values

  lbu  $s2, 0($a0)                                
  sb   $s2, 0($a1)         
                        
  addi $a0, $a0, 1        
  addi $a1, $a1, 1      
 
  bne  $s2, $zero, loop 

  jr $ra
```

print:

```
  li $v0, 4
  la $a0, T               # Print string T to the console
  syscall                 

  li $v0, 10              # Program Ends
  syscall
```

Comment: I have modified your code a bit and have added few important comments as well. I hope it might help you.